# Don't understand "(#4) User request limit reached"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, limit, facebook-oauth

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#4) User request limit reached",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

I'm not sure the cause of this error, and yes I've done lots of searching around for similar user's problems (they are error #17, or app limit reached). And I'm doing this on regular graph API calls (such as https://graph.facebook.com/me ), not necessarily FQL like others have run into.

`User request limit reached` makes it seem like a per-user limit, but according to http://www.fb-developers.info/tech/fb_dev/faq/general/gen_10.php , `#4` is `"Application request limit reached"` and `#17` is `"User request limit reached"`.

I don't believe there's anyway I'm hitting the 100M/day app limit. And I only get it for a couple users' auth tokens, so it's not an app-wide error message I'm getting. And when I request too quickly, I usually get `FQL_EC_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED`.

But for those two users with the above error `"(#4) User request limit reached"`, I've temporarily blacklisted them from loading data, but yet they *still* get the above error when I try to access using that auth token a day later.

So in conclusion...

I don't understand how I can get `"(#4) User request limit reached"` when the auth-token for that user is not being used for any queries in a 24-hour period prior. And I don't know what is special about these users.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. It was only one user a few days ago, but today a second user started running into this problem, and I'm worried the problem will just get worse in the future with no clear resolution.

Comment: Great question, voted it up for you!

Comment: I would submit all of your documentation on this issue as a bug to facebook since there's been no activity on this question.  Post your bug report as the answer.

Comment: I've never seen this error before. If we can replicate it, we might be able to figure out the cause. Is there any deterministic way to replicate it?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a list of error codes:  http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Error_codes

#4 means you've made too many API requests.  There are limits on how many your application can make given a certain amount of time.  There are also limits based on each user.  If you wait for a while the error should clear and allow you to make requests again.

The error codes are a throwback from older API's so it's possible they just combined #4 and #17 to always just return #4.

Also, the limits are not fixed such as "100M/day".  Go to Insights for your application and look under Diagnostics.  It will show you what requests are causing that error.  The limits vary from day to day and I think are related to how much other traffic there is.

Comment: Hi. I've got this error without any User and anu app (in public call). How is it possible ?

Comment: @mcbjam - don't all calls require an app id now?

Comment: No. Try to get data from this page ID. 464975223572738

Comment: @mcbjam - they may limit requests by IP in that case...  I have no idea.

Comment: I can make the call if a set a token. maybe a mix between IP and user